# I can't get embed a color space in a pdf for Pdf/A creation

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdfa

Here is my problem, I've made a java program with the library `PdfBox` to make pdf from the image and other `pdf` so this work fine, but I want to generate `PDF/A-1`. The problem is that I can't embed a color space.

**I've tried** the code of CreatePDFA.java that is given by PDFBox

```java
// Create output intent
InputStream colorProfile = CreatePDFA.class.getResourceAsStream("colorSpacePath");
PDOutputIntent oi = new PDOutputIntent(doc, colorProfile); 
oi.setInfo("sRGB IEC61966-2.1"); 
oi.setOutputCondition("sRGB IEC61966-2.1"); 
oi.setOutputConditionIdentifier("sRGB IEC61966-2.1"); 
oi.setRegistryName("http://www.color.org"); 
doc.getDocumentCatalog().addOutputIntent(oi);
```

I get a `NullPointerException` at the line:
`PDOutputIntent oi = new PDOutputIntent(doc, colorProfile);`

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.desktop/java.awt.color.ICC_Profile.getProfileDataFromStream(ICC_Profile.java:1034)
at java.desktop/java.awt.color.ICC_Profile.getInstance(ICC_Profile.java:1016)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDOutputIntent.configureOutputProfile(PDOutputIntent.java:112)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDOutputIntent.<init>(PDOutputIntent.java:49)
at src.Kairos.CreatePDFA.doIt(CreatePDFA.java:124)
at src.Kairos.CreatePDFA.main(CreatePDFA.java:153)
```

Comment: Is colorProfile Null? Please check.

Comment: @TilmanMy colorProfile is not Null, I'm sure of that. Here's what I discovered: the ICC_Profile class throw an IllegalArgumentException that say "Invalid ICC Profile Data". I tried to redownload the SRGB.icc file but nothing change. When going a little bit deeper, I discovered that the function read from the InputStream.java file return a negative's integer, with cause the getProfileDataFromStream method from the ICC_Profile.java fille return a null, with lead to a NullPointerExecption. I don't understand all of this so if anyone can help me

Comment: Does this also happen if you open try to create a FileInputStream of your downloaded ICC profile and pass that one to "ICC_Profile.getInstance" without using resource loading? What I'm thinking of is resource filtering. Are you using maven?

Comment: @Tilman I change the inputstream to an FileInputStream and it worked! silly me I could thought of that. Thank you man

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please delete your question or answer it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that work :

```
InputStream colorProfile = new FileInputStream(colorSpacePath);
PDOutputIntent oi = new PDOutputIntent(doc, colorProfile);
oi.setInfo("sRGB IEC61966-2.1");
oi.setOutputCondition("sRGB IEC61966-2.1");
oi.setOutputConditionIdentifier("sRGB IEC61966-2.1")
oi.setRegistryName("http://www.color.org");
doc.getDocumentCatalog().addOutputIntent(oi);
colorProfile.close()
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your InputStream colorProfile after construction.